# What does 'File "<string>"' stands for on python debugger and traceback?

Tags: python, pdb

Eventually, when I am in a debug session, the current file is named "<string>". What I would expect to see is the name of the module where the debugger is currently on.

The same happens on the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "~/project_x/app/services/contacts.py", line 23, in find_account
  account = self._account_repo.get_by_id(id)
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_by_id
  File "~/project_x/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", li
ne 528, in new_func
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the actual text instead!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the code came from something that was not a file, but a string. My guess would be an [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) call, but maybe there are other ways of getting the same effect. The previous stack frame might give some clues.

Comment: It is only a normal function invocation. I updated the traceback with the previous call.

Comment: I guess that it is caused by the ```@db_session``` decorator, from Pony ORM, used in the function. Thanks!